# file_get_contents does not work (wordpress)

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I'm trying to implement this supposedly working code on a WP site, the code currently sits in the child-theme's functions.php, everything seems to work, except it doesn't fetch the information from the file_get_contents() function. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
    $bizt_a = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://karteritesed.hu/biztositok.json"));
    $bizt_lista = "";
    foreach($bizt_a as $bizt){
    $bizt_lista .= "<option value=\"".$bizt."\">".$bizt."</option>";
    }
    
    $hhr_a = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://karteritesed.hu/hol_hallott_rolunk.json"));
    $hhr_lista = "";
    foreach($hhr_a as $hhr){
    $hhr_lista .= "<option value=\"".$hhr."\">".$hhr."</option>";
    }
    
    
    $jh_a = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://karteritesed.hu/javitas_helye.json"));
    $jh_lista = "";
    foreach($jh_a as $jh){
    $jh_lista .= "<option value=\"".$jh."\">".$jh."</option>";
    }
    
    if($_POST){
    
      $api_user = "";
      $api_key = "";
      $public_key = "";
      $user = "insurance";
    
    $array = array(
        "user" => $user,
        "public_key" => $public_key,
        "sikeres_url" => '',
        "sikertelen_url" => '',
        
        
        "v_nev" => @$_POST['v_nev'],
        "u_nev" => @$_POST['u_nev'],
        "email" => @$_POST['email'],
        "elso_uzembehelyezes" => @$_POST['elso_uzembehelyezes'],
        "karesemeny_idopont" => @$_POST['karesemeny_idopont'],
        "forgalmi_ertek" => @$_POST['forgalmi_ertek'],
        "munkadij" => @$_POST['munkadij'],
        "anyagkoltseg" => @$_POST['anyagkoltseg'],
        "rendszam" => @$_POST['rendszam'],
        "alvazszam" => @$_POST['alvazszam'],
        "futott_km" => @$_POST['futott_km'],
        "biztosito" => @$_POST['biztosito'],
        "hol_hallott_rolunk" => @$_POST['hol_hallott_rolunk'],
        "javitas_helye" => @$_POST['javitas_helye'],
        
        
        
    );
```

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` set to true in your `php.ini`

Comment: _"Any suggestions?"_ - any debugging attempts, so far, from your end? If Yes, then with what results? If No, then _why not_ ...?

Comment: if your using wp, you should probably use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/ then wp will spit out errors